# Laravel, replacing the whole session by an old one

Tags: php, session, laravel

I'm currently getting the whole session thanks to this code:

```
$session = Session::all();
```

For some reasons, this session has to be destroyed, and I would like to set it again after, with something like:

```
Session::setAll($session);
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($session as $key=>$value){
    Session::set($key, $value);
}
```